# Поставить по центру иконку в Radio-button в Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Пишу проект на Bootstrap. Столкнулся с неизвестной для меня проблемой. Я пытаюсь изменить стиль `radio-button` в Bootstrap на [этот](http://www.cssscript.com/demo/pretty-checkbox-radio-inputs-with-bootstrap-and-awesome-bootstrap-checkbox-css/).
Все подключил, все изменил, но местами сам шарик в середине контейнера `radio-button` не стоит по центру,хотя я ничего не изменял в CSS стиле взятого из примера, где кружек по центру.
При поиске причины неправильного расположения видел, что отступы такие как
`margin`, `padding`, кстати, установленные на 0px, влияют на отцентровку кружка.

Привожу пример:

```
<div class="radio radio-info radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="daysIntervalGroup" value="1" id="day-int-1"  data-bind="checked: daysInterval" />
                    <label for="day-int-1"  data-i18n="res:Day1" />
                </div>
```

Добавляю далее файл со стилем, взятый из примера.
Выходит вот что:

[image]

Далее просто выбираю другой `radio-button`, и шарик опять смещается совсем в другую сторону.

[image]

Что самое главное, когда я изменяю размер экрана в браузере, чтобы проверить масштабирование, то размещение кружка также изменяется непонятным образом.
Может ли влиять шрифт на размещения, и как могут влиять отступы на это все?
Уже не знаю, что и думать.

P.S: Подскажите, может есть лучший вариант изменить стили для `radio-button`? Но лучше помогите решить проблему.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="radio radio-info radio-inline">
 <input type="radio" name="daysIntervalGroup" value="1" id="day-int-1"  data-bind="checked: daysInterval" />
 <label for="day-int-1"  data-i18n="res:Day1" />
</div>
```

[ссылка на codepan](http://codepen.io/DavidKern/pen/yeBrBb)

[demo](http://www.cssscript.com/demo/pretty-checkbox-radio-inputs-with-bootstrap-and-awesome-bootstrap-checkbox-css/)

Answer (score 0):

Повлияло на данную ошибку стиль текста. Точнее стиль шрифта. Когда выставил повсюдю в стиляx: font-family: none; Все отлично заработал. При масштабировании работает также отлично.